# buffer and stream - how are they related?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, buffer

I am putting some code here:

```js
const { createReadStream, ReadStream } = require('fs');

var readStream = createReadStream('./data.txt');

readStream.on('data', chunk => {
  console.log('---------------------------------');
  console.log(chunk);
  console.log('---------------------------------');
});

readStream.on('open', () => {
  console.log('Stream opened...');
});

readStream.on('end', () => {
  console.log('Stream Closed...');
});
```

So, stream is the movement of data from one place to another. In this case, from `data.txt` file to my eyes since i have to read it.

I've read in google something like this:

> Typically, the movement of data is usually with the intention to
> process it, or read it, and make decisions based on it. But there is a
> minimum and a maximum amount of data a process could take over time.
> So if the rate the data arrives is faster than the rate the process
> consumes the data, the excess data need to wait somewhere for its turn
> to be processed.
>
> On the other hand, if the process is consuming the data faster than it
> arrives, the few data that arrive earlier need to wait for a certain
> amount of data to arrive before being sent out for processing.

My question is: which line of code is "consuming the data, processing the data" ? is it `console.log(chunk)` ? if I had a huge time consuming line of code instead of `console.log(chunk)`, how would my code not grab more data from buffer and wait until my processing is done ? in the above code, it seems like, it would still come into `readStream.on('data')'s` callback..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: which line of code is "consuming the data, processing the data"

The `readStream.on('data', ...)` event handler is the code that "consumes" or "processes" the data.

> if I had a huge time consuming line of code instead of console.log(chunk), how would my code not grab more data from buffer and wait until my processing is done ?

If the time consuming code is synchronous (e.g. blocking), then no more `data` events can happen until after your synchronous code is done because only your event handler is running (in the single-threaded event loop driven architecture of node.js).  No more `data` events will be generated until you return control back from your event handler callback function.

If the time consuming code is asynchronous (e.g. non-blocking and thus has returned control back to the event loop), then more `data` events certainly can happen even though a prior `data` event handler has not entirely finished it's asynchronous work yet.  It is sometimes appropriate to call `readStream.pause()` while doing asynchronous work to tell the readStream not to generate any more `data` events until you are ready for them and you can then `readStream.resume()`.